# How can I remove the login page when running OpenSearch Dashboards in Docker?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I'm running an OpenSearch instance in a docker container locally. I've added an OpenSearch Dashboards container alongside it, but there's a login screen when I access http://localhost:5601 in my browser. How can I disable the login page? This is just for local development.

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
  opensearch:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch
    container_name: opensearch-local
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    environment:
      discovery.type: single-node
      plugins.security.disabled: true
  opensearch-dashboards:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards
    container_name: opensearch-dashboards
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    expose:
      - "5601"
    environment:
      OPENSEARCH_HOSTS: '["http://opensearch-local:9200"]'
    depends_on:
      - opensearch
```

Answer (score 3):

There's an environment variable – `DISABLE_SECURITY_DASHBOARDS_PLUGIN` – you can set to disable security on the OpenSearch Dashboards container. I changed my `environment` configuration for the `opensearch-dashboard` service in my `docker-compose.yml` to:

```yaml
environment:
  OPENSEARCH_HOSTS: '["http://opensearch-local:9200"]'
  DISABLE_SECURITY_DASHBOARDS_PLUGIN: true
```

Found the answer here: https://github.com/opensearch-project/OpenSearch-Dashboards/issues/942#issuecomment-1081187658 and https://github.com/opensearch-project/OpenSearch/issues/1598#issuecomment-978189603